# Uploading large files with Rails 5 and Carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a `HTML` form for uploading video files in Rails 5. I am using `Carrierwave` with the standard generated uploader. Uploader with validation for file extension. When I try to upload large video files (2GB and more), I am getting this error:

```
Puma caught this error: failed to allocate memory (NoMemoryError)
```

This is full trace of the error:

```
Puma caught this error: failed to allocate memory (NoMemoryError)
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/multipart/parser.rb:186:in `on_read'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/multipart/parser.rb:72:in `block in parse'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/multipart/parser.rb:70:in `loop'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/multipart/parser.rb:70:in `parse'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/multipart.rb:52:in `extract_multipart'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/request.rb:472:in `parse_multipart'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/request.rb:335:in `POST'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/method_override.rb:39:in `method_override_param'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/method_override.rb:27:in `method_override'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/method_override.rb:15:in `call'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:27:in `call'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-livereload-0.3.16/lib/rack/livereload.rb:23:in `_call'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-livereload-0.3.16/lib/rack/livereload.rb:14:in `call'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:125:in `call'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:522:in `call'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.10.0/lib/puma/configuration.rb:225:in `call'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.10.0/lib/puma/server.rb:605:in `handle_request'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.10.0/lib/puma/server.rb:437:in `process_client'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.10.0/lib/puma/server.rb:301:in `block in run'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.10.0/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:120:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

I am using `Windows 10`. For production I will switch to `Linux`, but now I am developing in Windows. May be with Linux I will get same error, I don't know. How to upload large files with `Carrierwave` (even more than 5GB) ?

Comment: First off, Rails and Windows don't like each other. You really have to use Linux for Dev. Secondly: where do you store the files? On your server in a cloud?

Comment: Hi, thx for reply. I know about Windows and Rails, but for now, I  need to use it. The files are stored in local server.

Comment: Hmm ok, might sound a bit dull, but do you have enough space on your server for storing the file?

Comment: Yes. I am not sure I understand. Is there max size for space which is allocated for Puma ?

Comment: No, I don't know of any size limits for Puma or Carrierwave.